# How do I make my character move in GMod Hunger Games?

Tags: mods, garrys-mod

We just bought Donator for GMod Hunger Games and now my player won't move in any server.  It will spin, look up and down but it is stuck in one place!  What should we do?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your keybindings get messed up.  Try resetting your keys from the options menu.

Failing that, delete the `Steam\steamapps\common\GarrysMod\garrysmod\cfg` and `Steam\steamapps\<your username>\garrysmod\garrysmod\cfg` folders.

As a last resort, uninstall and reinstall Garry's Mod.